# Dynamodb max value

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using Dynamodb. I have a simple Employee table with fields like id, name, salary, doj, etc. What is the equivalent query of `select max(salary) from employee` in dynamodb?

Answer (score 10):

You can model your schema something like:

- `employee_id`, as partition-key
- `salary`, as sort-key of the table or local secondary index.

Then, `Query` your table for given `employee_id`, with `ScanIndexForward` as false, and pick the first returned entry. Since all rows one `employee_id` are stored in sorted fashion, the first entry in desc order will be the one with highest `salary`.

You can also keep `Limit` as 1, in which case DynamoDB will return only one record.

Relevant documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit).

Comment: Hi @ketan..thanks for your response...i created a index on emoployee_name and salary as sort key and queried as response = table.query(
    IndexName = 'Emp_Name-Salary-index',
    Limit = 1,
    ScanIndexForward = False,
    )...but this is giving me error as keyconditionexpression must be used. Im a newbie to dynamo.please help me where am i missing.

Comment: You haven't specified employee_id. Put that too

Comment: It seems this will only return the max salary *per employee*. The original SQL query is for 'global max'.

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya great note about Limit. It significantly improves performance of the query.

Comment: I can confirm what @tedder42 says. If you want to obtain the global maximum with this method, you will have to add a field that has the same value for all entries in your table (or if you already have a field that's the same for all entries, use that one), and then introduce a global secondary index that uses the newly introduced constant field as the HASH key and the salary as the RANGE key. From there the steps can be followed as outlined in this solution. Be sure to use the created global secondary index when querying!

Answer (score 2):

There is no cheap way to achieve this in Dynamodb. There is no inbuild function to determine the max value of an attribute without retrieving all items and calculate programmatically.

Comment: Is there another way to get the same result? Making an indexed query beforehand or so?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about `boto3` but in`boto` can be run this way

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

table = Table("employee")
values = list(table.query_2(reverse=True, limit=1))
MAXVALUE = values[0][salary]
```