# error with dynamo occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression:

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am a bit new to dynamodb

See error I get when trying to get the max id of my dynamodb table in python lambda function using instructions in below StackOverflow post in below link
[Dynamodb max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959515/dynamodb-max-value)

```
 An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: The expression can not be empty;\"}"
```

see my lambda function code below

```
import json
import boto3

TABLE_NAME = 'user-profiles'

dynamo_DB = boto3.resource('dynamodb')    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_id = event['user_id']
    email = event['email']
    bvn = event['bvn']
    password = event['password']
    phone = event['phone']
    gender = event['gender']

    output = ''


    if len(user_id) > 1 and len(password) > 5:
        try:


            table = dynamo_DB.Table(TABLE_NAME)

            values = list(table.query(
                KeyConditionExpression='',
                ScanIndexForward=False,
                Limit=1
                )
            )
            max_id = values[0]['id']
            new_id = max_id + 1

            Item = {
                'id': str(new_id),
                'profile-id': str(new_id),
                'user_id': user_id,
                'email': email,
                'bvn': bvn,
                'password': password,
                'phone': phone,
                'gender': gender
            }
            table.put_item(Item=Item)

            output += 'Data Inserted To Dynamodb Successfully'
        except Exception as e:
            output += 'error with dynamo registration ' + str(e)
            # print(output)

    else:
        output += 'invalid user or password entered, this is ' \
                  'what i received:\nusername: ' \
                  + str(user_id) + '\npassword: ' + str(password)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": output,
        }),
    }
    # print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `query` with empty `KeyConditionExpression`, if you need to read all records from the table you need to use [`scan`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan). But you cannot use `ScanIndexForward` there to order records forward.

Seems like you're trying to implement primary key incrementation. I want to warn you, your solution is not really awesome, because you easily can hit a race condition.

What I would suggest:
I guess you are using `id` as a primary key (aka partition key). it's okay. what I would do is upsert an extra record in the table, with say `increment` value:

```py
increment = table.update_item(
    Key={'id': 'increment'},
    UpdateExpression='ADD #increment :increment',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#increment': 'increment'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':increment': 1},
    ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW',
)

new_id = increment['Attributes']['increment']
```

This query will update the existing record with `id: 'increment'` and store a new incremented number in the record, if it is the very first query the record will be created with `increment: 1` and subsequent calls will increment it. ReturnValues means the query will return the result after the update and you will get a new id.

put the code in place instead of where you `query` the last record

so your code would look like:

```py
import json
import boto3

TABLE_NAME = 'user-profiles'

dynamo_DB = boto3.resource('dynamodb')    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_id = event['user_id']
    email = event['email']
    bvn = event['bvn']
    password = event['password']
    phone = event['phone']
    gender = event['gender']

    output = ''


    if len(user_id) > 1 and len(password) > 5:
        try:


            table = dynamo_DB.Table(TABLE_NAME)

            increment = table.update_item(
                Key={'id': 'increment'},
                UpdateExpression='ADD #increment :increment',
                ExpressionAttributeNames={'#increment': 'increment'},
                ExpressionAttributeValues={':increment': 1},
                ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW',
            )

            new_id = increment['Attributes']['increment']

            Item = {
                'id': str(new_id),
                'profile-id': str(new_id),
                'user_id': user_id,
                'email': email,
                'bvn': bvn,
                'password': password,
                'phone': phone,
                'gender': gender
            }
            table.put_item(Item=Item)

            output += 'Data Inserted To Dynamodb Successfully'
        except Exception as e:
            output += 'error with dynamo registration ' + str(e)
            # print(output)

    else:
        output += 'invalid user or password entered, this is ' \
                  'what i received:\nusername: ' \
                  + str(user_id) + '\npassword: ' + str(password)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": output,
        }),
    }
    # print(output)
```

and you're good.

**Extra thoughts:**

And to be 100% sure that there is no race condition on incrementation, you can implement a locking mechanism this way: Before incrementing, put an extra record with `id` value `lock` and `lock` attribute with any value, and use `ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(lock)'`. Then make an increment and then release the lock by removing the record `lock`. So while the record is there the second attempt to 'make a lock' would break by the condition that attribute `lock` exists and throw error `ConditionalCheckFailedException` (you can catch the error and show to a user that the record is locked or whatever.)

Here is an example in JavaScript sorry:

```js
module.exports.DynamoDbClient = class DynamoDbClient {
  constructor(tableName) {
    this.dynamoDb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

  async increment() {
    await this.lock();

    const {Attributes: {increment}} = await this.dynamoDb.update({
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: {id: 'increment'},
      UpdateExpression: 'ADD #increment :increment',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#increment': 'increment'},
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {':increment': 1},
      ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    }).promise();

    await this.unlock();

    return increment;
  }

  async lock(key) {
    try {
      await this.dynamoDb.put({
        TableName: this.tableName,
        Item: {id: 'lock', _lock: true},
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#lock)',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#lock': '_lock'},
      }).promise();
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
        throw new LockError(`Key is locked.`);
      }

      throw error;
    }
  }

  unlock() {
    return this.delete({id: 'lock'});
  }

  async delete(key) {
    await this.dynamoDb.delete({
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: key,
    }).promise();
  }
}

// usage

const client = new DynamoDbClient('table');
const newId = await client.increment();

...
```

Comment: Hi @Floyd your Answer is awesome. the only issue is I am having a new error:  "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema".  How do I resolve this please

Comment: I need more info what primary key you set in your table? Is `profile-id` a sort key there?

Comment: yes @Floyd, the field "id" is the partition key(primary key) and "profile-id" is the sort key

Comment: Then use the following Key in update increment query : `Key={'id': 'increment', 'profile-id': '#'}`, instead of # you can use any value, it does not really matter what values you use in your increment key , the idea is having an extra record which will keep the next increment for your new normal records

Comment: You can also create a separate table for storing this increment, otherwise  if you gonna scan your user-profile  table and display them all somewhere , it will also show this increment record, but the best practice using dynamodb is avoid using `scan` and design your table using secondary indexes for different access patterns

Comment: thanks so much Your code suggestions are perfect. You are a superstar. so I owe you a drink.  :)enjoy your day

Comment: @MIikeEps glad it works, don't forget to choose an answer for your question

Comment: I have done it.
Can you also help me with this similar issue in this post here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077899/python-lambda-an-error-occurred-validationexception-when-calling-the-query-ope